# Strange behavior when lambda uses `this` vs "outside instance"

Tags: c++, lambda, arduino, interrupt, arduino-nano

I'm trying to keep my code well-organized as I learn C++ for Arduino (specifically Nano in my case). There's a function `attachInterrupt()` that allows me to bind a hardware interrupt to a specific pin when it undergoes a state change.

> **Signature:** `void attachInterrupt(uint8_t interruptNum, void (*userFunc)(void), int mode)`

So far, so good. However, I've created a class to manage a specific aspect of my program. This way, I can reuse the code instead of redoing the `setup()` multiple times.

So, imagine I have a certain type of digital sensor and I'm going to use `attachInterrupt()` for it. Normally, I would write the following code:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>

unsigned int count = 0;

void countISR() {
  count++;
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(PIN2, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(PIN2), countISR, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Count = " + String(count));
  delay(1000);
}
```

This tends to work very well. However, as mentioned, I'd like to better organize my code and allow for code reuse for various interrupt-supporting pins (or even using libraries like *EnableInterrupt*, but that's beside the point).

Therefore, I created a class called `Counter`:

```cpp
class Counter {
  public:
    uint8_t pin;
    unsigned int count = 0;

    Counter(uint8_t pin): pin(pin) {}

    void setup() {
      pinMode(pin, INPUT);
      // attachInterrupt() should go here.
    }

    void update() {
      count++;
    }
};
```

This way, I can instantiate multiple independent `Counter`s, something like:

```cpp
Counter counterA(PIN2);
Counter counterB(PIN3);

void setup() {
  counterA.setup(); // Set pinMode() and interrupt to PIN2.
  counterB.setup(); // Set pinMode() and interrupt to PIN3.
}
```

However, when trying to perform an `attachInterrupt()` inside `Counter::setup()`, I need to create a C++ Lambda, and I would typically do something like:

```cpp
void Counter::setup() {
  // pinMode(...)
  attachInterrupt(pin, []() { update(); }, CHANGE);
}
```

In theory, this should be enough. But C++ indicates that I can't do it this way, issuing the following error:

> **Error:** the enclosing-function 'this' cannot be referenced in a lambda body unless it is in the capture list. C/C++ (1738)

Alright, so let's try putting `this` in the capture list:

```cpp
void Counter::setup() {
  // pinMode(...)
  attachInterrupt(pin, [this]() { update(); }, CHANGE);
}
```

And now there's another error:

> **Error:** no suitable conversion function from "lambda ->void" to "void (*)()" exists. C/C++(413)

I understand the reason for the error, as it conflicts with the signature of `attachInterrupt()`. However, if I do this within the main `void setup()`, it will work:

```cpp
void setup() {
  // pinMode(...)
  attachInterrupt(PIN2, []() { counterA.update(); }, CHANGE);
}
```

In other words, one way or another, I'm passing an instance into a lambda without even needing to capture it explicitly.

So I thought: maybe the problem is the use of `this`, so I tried assigning it to a variable first, like:

```cpp
void Counter::setup() {
  // pinMode(...)

  const auto self = this;
  attachInterrupt(pin, []() { self.update(); }, CHANGE);
}
```

The error changes, but it's practically the same as the first one:

> **Error:** an enclosing-function local variable cannot be referenced in a lambda body unless it is in the capture list. C/C++(1735)

This left me quite confused: why is it allowed to do this outside of a class, but inside it, I need to go through this capture process?

To solve the problem for now, I had to make an adjustment that I found ugly:

```cpp
void setup() {
  counterA.setup([]() { counterA.update(); })
}
```

Thus, in `Counter::setup()`, I receive a lambda in the format allowed by `attachInterrupt()`, already capturing `counterA` or `counterB` without problems.

So, what am I doing so wrong?

Comment: AttachInterupt only accepts "void (*)()" function pointers (so no return value, no arguments). This rules out passing non-static member functions (they require an implicit fisrt argument pointing to the instance of the class). You also cannot pass lambda's with captures (they are not convertible to function pointers either). So in the end I think you're last option is the only real one that will work.